# How to remove clear selection option from options menu of ArcGIS feature table?

Tags: arcgis-online

I am using ArcGIS Online and ArcGIS's feature table. I want to remove "Clear Selection" option from options menu i.e. present on the right corner(please check image's red border area).[image]

Do you have any solution for this requiremt?

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not configurable in the map viewer. I would recommend posting this on the ideas page and why you would want the clear selection option hidden/removed.